# return the element from a 'a' tag?

Tags: javascript, html

why does this not return the element? it returns the href attribute on the tag

```
var tst = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
tst.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.test.com');
alert(tst);
```

Comment: that is correct behaviour. It should work that way.

Comment: how can I then get the element as an object?

Comment: use `console.log` with Firebug, or any other DOM inspector to see what the variable *actually* contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **does** return an element..... `.nodeType` is `1` and `.nodeName` is `A` if you actually test it.

Anchor elements' toString method probably just return the url for certain DOM implementations.

Comment: you are correct :) it just looked like a string when you alert the object